# Exposition about Ergodic Entropy

Tags: reference-request, ergodic-theory

does anybody could suggest me any book or paper about Entropy in Ergodic Theory?
I'm trying to prepare an exposition but I've just 30/40 minutes more or less so I'd like to choose a theme, or some theme interesting about it without loosing anything important.
Since I'm not that skilled about it I hope that somebody could help suggesting me a scheme or a possible list of main topic I can choose between.
Also paper about it or book will be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: what books do you know?

Comment: What kind of audience is this for? Some kind of introductory seminar for master/phd students?

Comment: Master students.At the end of a course everyone has an addictional theme to present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael Brin and Garret Stuck pdf book http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/Diff.Equations/Brin%20M.,%20Stuck%20G.,%20Introduction%20to%20Dynamical%20Systems,%202003.pdf (metric entropy chapter 9)

survey by Lai Sang Young  http://cims.nyu.edu/~lsy/papers/entropy.pdf

Comment: I very much second the Lai Sang Young survey!

Answer (score 1):

There is a several papers and books about this matter.

1. The Brin Stuck Book, the last chapther is about metric entropy. (I think it's the best introduction that I know)
2. The Katok-Hasselblatt  book, A Modern Introduction  to Dynamical Systems(It has an approach similar to the previous reference but with more detailed calculations)
3. The Lai Sang Young Survey, Entropy in Dynamical Systems ( Gives an overview of the theory, but without calculations.)
4. The  Bowens Book ,Equilibrium States and the Ergodic Theory of Anosov Diffeomorphisms, (Besides being very introductory has many references at the end of each chapter.)
5. Entropy in Dynamical Systems - Tomasz Downarowicz -( this book is very detailed. deals with the subject in a profound way)